Issues with UPDATE and DELETE Queries Using redis_fdw in PostgreSQL
I am using redis_fdw in a PL/pgSQL function to interact with a Redis server, and I’ve encountered issues with certain queries. Here is the summary:
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE redis_db7 (key text, val text)
SERVER redis_server
OPTIONS (database '7');

Bulk Insert: The following query works perfectly:
INSERT INTO redis_db7 (key, val) 
SELECT key, agg(...) AS val 
FROM mytable 
INNER JOIN ... 
GROUP BY ...;

Update Issue: The following query fails:
UPDATE redis_db7 r 
SET val = n.val 
FROM (
    SELECT key, agg(...) AS val 
    FROM mytable 
    INNER JOIN ... 
    GROUP BY ...
) n
WHERE r.key = n.key;

In this case, I get the error: [XX000] ERROR: could not find pathkey item to sort.
Delete Issue: The following query also doesn’t behave as expected:
DELETE 
FROM redis_db7 r 
USING (
    SELECT key
    FROM mytable 
    INNER JOIN ... 
    GROUP BY ...
) n 
WHERE r.key = n.key;

This query sometimes runs without error [XX000] ERROR: could not find pathkey item to sort. , but the corresponding keys in Redis are not deleted, and takes too long.
My Questions:
Are these operations (UPDATE ... FROM and DELETE ... USING) supported by redis_fdw?
If not, is there a recommended workaround for bulk updates and deletes when using redis_fdw with Redis?
Is there any known issue causing the [XX000] ERROR: could not find pathkey item to sort. error?
I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve these issues.
Thanks in advance for your help!
